# Sweet alert error. Undefined type 'RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert'

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

I have no clue to solve this error.

In `config/app.php` I put this in providers:

```
RealRashid\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider::class,
```

and this in aliases:

```
'Alert' => RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert::class,
```

In my layout I use this:

```
@include('sweetalert::alert')
```

and in the controller I put this:

```
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
```

I put in the terminal composer dump-autoload but still not working.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured package correctly? I think you are missing publishing package assets step.

Run the below command to publish the package assets.

`php artisan sweetalert:publish`

Comment: Glad that worked for you! you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This comes to a bulk project which have alot of cache, kindly clear the cache by running the command

```
 php artisan optimize:clear
```

then make sure you publish the package assets by running the command

```
php artisan sweetalert:publish
```